# Swift: Creating array of objects with generic type parameter

Tags: swift, generics

I have a type called `Setting` that takes a generic type parameter as such:

```
Setting<T>
```

Every setting contains a value that can be an Int32, String, Bool, or a custom object type, etc. Here is some of the full implementation of Setting:

```
class Setting<T> {
    var key:String?
    var defaultValue:T?
    //...
}
```

This all works with various type params as expected, however, now there is a requirement for a collection that contains multiple `Setting` objects that could have various type parameters. When I declare an array variable of type `[Setting]`, obviously the compiler expects a type which is unknown at runtime.

I've tried using a protocol and an extension on the types that could be used for the generic type parameter such as this:

```
protocol SettingProtocol {
    func getType() -> Self.Type
}

extension Int32:SettingProtocol {
    func getType() -> Int32.Type {
        return Int32.self
    }
}

extension String:SettingProtocol {
    func getType() -> String.Type {
        return String.self
    }
}
//...
```

and declaring my array as

```
var settings = [Setting<SettingProtocol>]()
```

but this does not work when I try to append a `Setting` instance to the array as follows:

```
var newSetting = Setting<String>()
newSetting.setDefaultValue(value: "SomeString")
settings?.append(newSetting) // compile error here
```

and results in the following compiler error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Setting<String>' to expected argument type 'Setting<SettingProtocol>'
```

Also, using the protocol/extension route might require an extension on every type that might be encountered when building these objects which seems really clunky.

I feel like there should be a way to accomplish this. Also hoping that when I pull these items out of the array that I can avoid a lot of type checking.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
class Setting<T>
```

to

```
class Setting<T:SettingProtocol>
```

and try compiling.

Comment: Won't resolve it. "Using 'SettingProtocol' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'SettingProtocol' is not supported".

Comment: @AhmadF You're correct. I had to make my Setting class conform to a protocol, and now it works

Comment: @Pheepster What?! How is a valid answer? Would you mention what have you done to make it work?!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can't define:

```
var settings = [Setting<SettingProtocol>]()
```

because the generic type of `Setting` must be one of the concrete types but *not* the protocol itself. For example, you could declare it as:

```
var settings = [Setting<String>]() // since you already implemented extension String:SettingProtocol { ...
```

Therefore you could append objects of type `Setting<String>`, however that's not what are you looking for, you need `settings` to be a *heterogeneous* container.

So what you could do is:

```
class Setting {
    var key:String?
    var defaultValue:SettingProtocol?
}

protocol SettingProtocol { }
extension Int32:SettingProtocol {}
extension String: SettingProtocol {}
```

At this point, you declared `defaultValue` to be of type `SettingProtocol`, without the need of dealing with a generic.

Therefore:

```
var newStringSetting = Setting()
newStringSetting.defaultValue = "My String"
settings.append(newStringSetting)

var newInt32Setting = Setting()
newInt32Setting.defaultValue = Int32(100)
settings.append(newInt32Setting)

for setting in settings {
    print(setting.defaultValue)
    // Optional("My String")
    // Optional(100)
}
```